# How to use a backup db connection using PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that handles my db connection. In casse my main DB isn't available I want to use a backup one.
I tried to do so using below code but it's not working...

```
$host = 'xxx';
$database = 'xxx';
$login = 'xxx';
$pass = 'xxx';

if (! mysql_connect( $host, $login, $pass ) )
{
    // try to connect to backup db
    $host = 'yyy';
    $database = 'yyy';
    $login = 'yyy';
    $pass = 'yyy';
mysql_connect ( $host, $login, $pass ) or die ( "Failed to connect to the database: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db ( $database ) or die ( "Failed to find the database" . mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

I'm sure about my connection parameters, so the problem isn't there

Edit:
I'm using an old version of php so I'm limited to Mysql_*
My 1st server is currently down, and I'm getting a 'Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Too many connections in ...' error

In fact my problem is that I need NOT to print this warning message if the 1st connection failed...

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: What's not working? What is the error message you get? We are not mind readers.

Comment: Why are you even trying to do this with the ancient `mysql_query` interface?

Comment: it dies at the 1st connection, it doesn't try the second one

Comment: I'm having a real issue when connecting to the 1st server (server unavailable because of too many connections). I want my code to switch to the second servers, but it doesn't even try to connect to the 2nd server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When php fails to connect, it generates a warning, which stops the php execution.
You may use @mysql_connect (function name prefixed with an "@") to avoid the warning. And your code will continue to execute, even if first sql server does not respond. crappy, but working.

Comment: thx ! That was cleaner than my workaround using error_reporting(0);

Comment: A warning does not stop code execution. An `@` doesn't help with situations that *actually* stop code execution.

Comment: @deceze Yes it does because the warning is printed, and I'm receiving it as part of the response.

Comment: @user Yes, `@` suppresses errors, which in your case is what you want. The rest of Armage's explanation is incorrect though.

Comment: @deceze Ok, the documentation says the same as you, but why is the second connection not processed ? Even in cli php, this sort of test stopped after failing on the first connection. So it "seems" to stop the execution.

Answer (score 2):

**Please note Mysql_* is deprecated, use mysqli_ or PDO which is far more secure.**

Have you tried outputting the error? I don't see it in your code.

*I haven't used mysql_* for a long time, but try outputting the error using:* `mysql_error()`

As mentioned, it could be a variety of problems:

- Mysql isn't started
- Firewall is blocking the connection
- Not using default port
- ...

Edit:
Also you may want to look into setting up replecation for such events as DB failure.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this in your code, just use something like [MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/) to do it for you.

Comment: I cannot install anything on the server, that's why I need to handle it in my code.
It's just a backup solution in case the main DB crash. I don't care it's slow I just need something that works while I can fix the main server

Comment: What you're asking for is basically impossible. Any application that uses `mysql_query` is going to be littered with all kinds of assumptions about the nature of the connection, and with connection pooling, which is almost always turned on in some capacity, you'll have piles of dead connections you need to kill off and no way of doing it. A proxy is really the only way to do this reliably, it handles it at the connection level. Anything else will only create more problems than it solves.

Comment: MySQL Proxy doesn't have to be installed on the database server, either. It can be installed on any server you have the ability to install software on so long as it can connect to the various MySQL servers involved.

Comment: I cannot install anything on any server (the one that runs PHP or the DB server) ;)
I can make it work by disabling error reporting ( error_reporting(0); ) before the 1st connection and restoring it after...

Comment: If you're looking for redundancy, hosting PHP and the MySQL process on the same machine, you're already in a no-win situation. If your MySQL server crashes, you won't have any PHP to run, so the replica database is worthless.

Comment: I'm not hosting them on the same server otherwise my question wouldn't have any meaning ;)
I'm just saying that I cannot install additional library/plugins on any of my servers

Comment: They're asking you to make a jet plane out of a wooden spoon, so good luck with that.

Comment: There's no They. It's just me and my current Hosting limitation ;)